# Why can't I minimize and maximize my collection?

Tags: collections, outliner

I clicked on the button but nothing happened

[image: I clicked on the button but nothing happening]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi :). There's no good reason it shouldn't work. Consider restarting blender, removing and adding a new collection or you can also report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu *Edit > Preferences > Keymap* and search *Open/Close*.
When you find it, click on the arrow behind the first of them and click on the box 3 that says *Press* or *Click* and change it to another one.

Then click on 3-line box below the window and save preferences.